# Terms smaller than a number from a condition

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-explanation

This is a question for a proof in [Theorem 4.2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870813003575#se0040).

> Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be some numbers from a relation satisfying that 
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1+|a_n|}{\sqrt{b_n b_{n-1}}}<\infty
> $$
>   Put $\epsilon_{n}:=\frac{|z|+|a_n|}{\sqrt{b_n b_{n-1}}}$. In the proof, it says that ".. and by assumption $\epsilon_n<1$ for $n$ sufficiently large depending on $z$". Why is this the case?

We know that the terms in the summation tends to $0$, because it converges, so we can make it as small as we want. So I think it's something about finding the upper bound of
$$
\epsilon_n=\frac{1+|a_n|}{\sqrt{b_n b_{n-1}}}+\frac{|z|-1}{\sqrt{b_n b_{n-1}}}
$$
for large $n$. If this is true, I do not know what to do for the last terms on the right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the fraction
$$
\frac{1+|a_n|}{\sqrt{b_n b_{n-1}}}
$$
approaches $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity, and noting that the numerator is always at least $1$, it follows that the denominator approaches infinity.

Hence for a fixed value of $z$, the fraction
$$
\frac{|z|-1}{\sqrt{b_n b_{n-1}}}
$$
approaches $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity.